# I want to tag a person who clicks a button discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

[image: 1st image]
[image: 2nd image]

```
components = [
    [
        Button(label="Open a ticket", style=2, custom_id="Open", emoji="")
    ]
]
await ctx.send(embed=embed, components=components )
while True:
    interaction = await client.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.component.label.startswith("Open"))
    overwrites = {
        member_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False),
        ctx.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True),
        guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True),
        ticket_mod_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True)
    }

    Embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Ticket Created",
        description=f"{THIS EMPTY SPACE} Your ticket is created", 
    )

    await interaction.send(content = await interaction.send(embed=Embed), ephemeral=True)
    ticket = await ticket_category.create_text_channel(
        f"│Ticket-{THIS EMPTY SPACE}", overwrites=overwrites
    )

    Embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Ticket Created",
        url="",
        description=f"""{ctx.author.name} Wait our staff.""",
        color=discord.Color.random()
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've resolved using the library of discord.py (interaction) instead of this i used the object (user.name)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ctx.author.name (ctx.author is a discord.member class)

Use ctx.author.mention

Docs:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=mention#discord.Member.mention

Answer (score 0):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_buttons_plugin import *

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', intents=intents)
buttons = ButtonsClient(client)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Log : "+str(client.user))

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def ticket(ctx):
    em = discord.Embed(title="join us",description="To create a ticket react with",emoji={"id": None,"name": "","animated": False},color=discord.Color.from_rgb(0,255,0))
    await buttons.send(embed=em,channel=ctx.channel.id,
    components=[ActionRow([Button(style= ButtonType().Secondary,label = "Create ticket",custom_id = "test1")])])
    
@buttons.click
async def test1(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    ch = await guild.create_text_channel(name=f'ticket-{ctx.member}')
    await ch.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role,view_channel=False,send_messages=False)
    await ch.set_permissions(ctx.member,view_channel=True,send_messages=True)
    await ctx.reply(f"Ticket created {ch.mention}",flags=MessageFlags().EPHEMERAL)


client.run("token")
```